# What is touch event in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am just started with WPF.
Why there is need to have touch events ?
Any Example ...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try running the samples on this blog:

- [Introduction to WPF 4 Multitouch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx)

You need a tablet or multi-touch provider to exercise some of these features.  You can simulate touch interface with a mouse or multiple mice using this project:

- [Multi-Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/)