# Can my WPF application run in touch screen?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, operating-system, touchscreen

I am creating a WPF application in Visual Studio 2012.

Can I deploy and use this application through a touch screen environment?

Then what windows OS should I select ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what .NET version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes, My collegue has done a project for press reviews that runs in touch screen on Win7 Pro machine. Refer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx) for documentation.

Refer also this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747185/what-is-touch-event-in-wpf)